# The K&R method of reducing arrays to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

**The K&R method of reducing arrays to pointers:**(An excerpt from [arrays and pointers in C](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html))

K&R tried to create a unified treatment of arrays and pointers, one that 
 would expose rather than hide the array equation in the compiler's code. 
 They found an elegant solution, albeit a bit complicated. The "ugly" 
 array equation is replaced in their formulation by four rules:

```
1) An array of dimension N is a 1D array with
   elements that are arrays of dimension N-1.

2) Pointer addition is defined by:

      ptr # n = ptr + n * size(type-pointed-into)

   "#" denotes here pointer addition to avoid 
   confusion with ordinary addition.
   The function "size()" returns object's sizes.

3) The famous "decay convention": an array is 
   treated as a pointer that points to the 
   first element of the array.

   The decay convention shouldn't be applied
   more than once to the same object.

4) Taking a subscript with value i is equivalent 
   to the operation: "pointer-add i and then 
   type-dereference the sum", i.e.

      xxx[i] = *(xxx # i)


    When rule #4 + rule #3 are applied recursively 
    (this is the case of a multi-dimensional array), 
    only the data type is dereferenced and not the 
    pointer's value, except on the last step.
```

I do not understand what does it mean by

> - **The decay convention shouldn't be applied more than once to the same object** (in rule #3).
> - When rule #4 + rule #3 are applied recursively  (this is the case of a multi-dimensional array), **only the data type is dereferenced and not the pointer's value, except on the last step.**

Could someone explain it with examples?

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Source had been cited in the question (at the end of first line).

Answer (score 1):

Try to study this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int a[] = {42, 1, 5, 89, 7};
  int step = 3;

  int b = a[step];        // step 1
  printf("%d\n", b);

  b = *(a + step);        // step 2
  printf("%d\n", b);

  b = *(step + a);        // step 3
  printf("%d\n", b);

  b = step[a];            // step 4
  printf("%d\n", b);

  return (0);
}
```

This is possible because:

- an array is granted to be a contiguos chunk of memory containing variables/slots of the same type
- to both the `[]` operator and the pointer dereferencing you apply the same arithmetic, the same pointer arithmetic

  - this is the key point, pointers and arrays are not the same thing, the same arithmetic applies to both pointers and arrays in this case when you can consider an array as a pointer or as an array with the `[]` operator, but pointers and arrays are 2 different constructs, 2 different things.

EDIT:

I added a *step 4* just to clarify the similarity between the pointer aliasing and the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you have provided in the question, consider the following example:

```
int mat[i][j]
mat[i][j] = *(*(mat + i * sizeof(row)) # j)
```

- When rule #4 + rule #3 are applied recursively (this is the case of a multi-dimensional array), only the data type is dereferenced and not the pointer's value, except on the last step. This mean that `*(mat + i * sizeof(row))` dereferences an aggregate which in our case is "an array of integers with j elements". Only the second dereference operation which is `*(*(mat + i * sizeof(row)) # j)` gives you an actual `int`.
- The above holds since the decay occurs only once ie. `*(mat + i * sizeof(row))` is a pointer, which points to an int array".

Comment: What does it mean by *derefrencing a data type*?

Comment: @haccks: Consider an `x` of type `int *` which holds a pointer to some `int`. `x` is a reference to the `int`. It is not the `int`, just information about it. Next, consider the expression `*x`. This expression is the `int` that `x` points to. It is no longer a reference to the object; it is the object. Since the reference is gone, applying the `*` operator is called dereferencing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; I know derefrencing: referring to the data pointer points to. But *dereferencing a data type* is new to me.

Comment: @haccks I agree, *dereferencing a datatype* was wrong. Changed it, does it make sense now ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Lets not use the word *reference* here, since we are talking about C, not C++, BTW, references and pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: @mishr: Since the question was about what “dereferencing” means, it was necessary to talk about references. The C standard itself uses the word “referenced” in discussing pointers.